# How to set SparkSession.readStream properties in a configuration file?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I am using spark structured streaming for the first time and also a Spark session for the first time with Kafka. I know how to set conf properties using a config file for Spark context but I don't see it so straightforward with spark session.
Below I have my Spark session configuration

```scala
val incoming_data = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "boot_strap_server_list")
  .option("subscribe", "topic_name")
  .load()
```

Comment: I think you need to create your own application specific config items and load those.  See Typesafe's Config library on how to do that.  https://github.com/lightbend/config

Comment: At the start of the application you need to load your properties file (however way you like).. for example if you choose a json file, read the file, parse the json, then access it by key to retrieve the property value you want